# Change mat-progress-bar "aria-valuemax"

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

is there any way to change aria-valuemax="100" of Angular material progress bar?

As a project in my formation, I work on a citybuilder. I use mat-progress-bar in my ressource bar. The problem is when the stock is for example: 50 max iron, then the max progress bar is at 50% of the bar.

And I find the "aria-valuemax" in mat-progress-bar files. I tried to change this value in the html page:

```
<mat-progress-bar class="energy-progress" [value]= "energy" aria-valuemax="energyMax">
```

but it doesn't work. Is it possible in a nother way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not map the energy value directly. Do a percentage calculation before mapping.

For example:

```
energyProgress = energy*100/energyMax
< mat-progress-bar class="energy-progress" [value]= "energyProgress" >
```